# Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token) on google plus share interactive post using javascript render method

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-plus

Everything working fine.But while i click browse people icon in google plus share interactive post it just shows Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token). As mentioned in this image

[image]

[image: It show message like this]

And i have used following code for interactive post.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Share Demo: Deferred execution with language code</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
  window.___gcfg = {
            lang: 'en-US',
            parsetags: 'explicit'
          };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
    <div id ="sharePost">Share</div>
 <script>
     (function() {
           var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
           po.src = 'http://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js';
           var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
         })();
     var options = {
                contenturl: 'http://www.google.com',
                contentdeeplinkid: '/pages',
                clientid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                prefilltext: 'Hai happy friday'+ Math.random(),
                calltoactionlabel: 'INVITE',
                calltoactionurl: 'http://www.google.com'
              };
              // Call the render method when appropriate within your app to display
              // the button.
              gapi.interactivepost.render('sharePost', options);

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest adding a substantial amount of information to this post because we can't guess at what your problem is from a bunch of screenshots. We need a link to the thing that you're trying to implement, and the code that you have. Without this, it's a close vote from me.

Comment: I have edited my post with coding i have used @spender

Answer (score 0):

google's doc are up to date. Implementing interactive post is easy and well explain.
If it doesn't work :

1. it's a bug in Google code (i think it's that here)
2. It's a bug in Google doc which is not up to date

In all case the culprit is Google ! :)